# Getting a TypeError in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parse through genealogy data with the goal of creating a dictionary of the name, date, and number of occurrences (to make sure there are no duplicate individual entries). Here is an example:

```
0 NOTE the lines until the next note are all correct
0 HEAD
0 jc INDI
1 NAME Jimmy /Connors/
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE 1 JAN 1950
1 DEAT
2 DATE 31 DEC 2099
1 FAMC f1
1 FAMS f2
0 f2 FAM
1 HUSB jc
1 WIFE ce
1 CHIL aa
1 MARR 
2 DATE 1 JUN 1960
1 DIV
2 DATE 1 JUN 1961
0 TRLR
0 NOTE Everything past this line is invalid
0 INDI id
0 FAM id
0 NAME invalid
0 SEX invalid
0 BIRT invalid
0 DEAT invalid
0 FAMC invalid
0 FAMS invalid
0 MARR invalid
0 HUSB invalid
0 WIFE invalid
0 CHIL invalid
0 DIV invalid
0 DATE invalid
1 INDI invalid
1 FAM invalid
1 HEAD 
1 TRLR
1 DATE
1 NOTE bad note
1 DATE 1 JUN 2017
2 INDI id
2 FAM id
2 NAME invalid
2 SEX invalid
2 BIRT invalid
2 DEAT invalid
2 FAMC invalid
2 FAMS invalid
2 MARR invalid
2 HUSB invalid
2 WIFE invalid
2 CHIL invalid
2 DIV invalid
1 INVALID invalid
3 INVALID invalid
4 NOTE invalid
```

Here is my code so far (not complete because I'm getting stuck):

```
'''

No more than one individual with the same name and birth date
should appear in a GEDCOM file

'''
file_name = input("Give me a file name to parse (in single quotes): ")
target1 = 'NAME'
target2 = 'BIRT'
name = ''
count = 0
person_dict = {}

try:
    file = open(file_name)
except IOError:
    raise IOError("Can't open '{}'".format(file_name))

for index, line in enumerate(file):
    word = line.strip().split()
    if target1 in word:
        name = word[index-1:]
        arguments = " ".join(word[index-1:])
        person_dict[name] = arguments
        print(person_dict)
    elif target2 in word:
        birth = word[index-1:index+3]
        clean_bdate = " ".join(word[index-1:index+3])
        person_dict[date] = clean_bdate
        print(birth)
    else:
        print('not name')

'''
if duplicates are found...
    print("{} already exists. Removing duplicate entry.".format(arguments))
'''
```

I keep getting

> File "user_story_1.py", line 24, in 
>       person_dict[name] = arguments TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

and I've tried many things including making my list a tuple, but nothing seems to be working. Apologies if this seems like a basic question, I'm new to programming and I've been stuck for a while!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python, dictionary accepts only hashable types as keys.

list is not a hashable type. but, tuple is. so, it should work with tuple.

to check if hashable you can use hash function as below

[image: Hashable]

Based on your error, here is the answer

```
person_dict[name] = arguments
```

first thing here `name` is a `list`.

so, just convert it to a tuple as below

```
person_dict[tuple(name)] = arguments
```

Note, even if tuple has one of its element as a list, its not hashable.

Comment: Hi, updated my error to show the line where the error occurs. For that line I'm trying to add the name I get to the dictionary. Also making it a tuple didn't work.

Comment: @Rachel, there is no code that you showed in the traceback